# Fedora Server as Access point

Tags: fedora, wifi, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq, hostapd

I following [this guide](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) (for Rasbian) to use Fedora server 26 as a access point on the Raspberry Pi 3. I made some changes in the configs to make it work on Fedora.

My configs are as follow:

**hostapd.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=wheel

macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

driver=nl80211
interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
channel=6
ssid=Fedora
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
wpa_passphrase=MyP@ssw0rd
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-wlan0**

```
HWADDR=d8:28:eb:5c:45:7a
DEVICE="wlan0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Wireless"
IPADDR=172.24.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
interface=wlan0     
listen-address=172.24.1.1  
bind-interfaces  
server=8.8.8.8        
domain-needed        
bogus-priv             
dhcp-range=172.24.1.50,172.24.1.150,12h
```

**NAT**

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

The access point is visible to the clients and they can connect to it. The strange thing is that when clients are trying to connect to a website the connection to the access point is immediately disconnected. I see nothing in the log files except:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (Operation not supported)
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
```

How to make this work?

Comment: no insult intended, but does your wifi device show up as wlan0?  and does it support AP mode?